# One background image vs repeating pattern/images, for Corona SDK game?

Tags: coronasdk

What would be a better approach in Corona re static background for a 2D scrolling based game?

Let's say the game level "size" is the equivalent of two screens wide and two screens deep.

Q1 - Would one large background image be an OK approach? This would probably be easier as you could do the work in Photoshop to prepare. Or is there a significant advantage (re performance) in Corona to have a small image "pattern" and repeat this in Corona ([Lua](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_%28programming_language%29) code) to create the backdrop?

Q2 - If one large background image approach is OK, would I assume that one might have to sacrifice the resolution of the image, noting the size (2xscreens wide, and 2xscreens deep) correct for the higher resolution devices? That is for the [iPad 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPad_%283rd_generation%29) say, assuming your configuration would normally would try to pickup the 3x image version (for other images, say smaller play icons, etc.) that for the background you might have to remain with the 1x or 2x image size. Otherwise, it may hit the texture limit (I've read "Most devices have a maximum texture size of 2048x2048"). Is this correct / does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used both approaches on my games.

Advantages of tiled mode:

1. You can make huge backgrounds.
2. Can be made to use less memory (specially with smallish tiles with lots of repeating, like a real world wallpaper)
3. Allow for some interesting effects (like parallax scrolling).

Problems of tiled mode:

1. Use more CPU performance
2. Might be buggy and hard to make behave correctly (for example one of my games gaps showed between tiles, but only on iPad Retina... it required some heavy math hackery to make it work)
3. It is hard to make complex and awesome backgrounds (reason why my point and click adventure games don't use tiled backgrounds).

Pay attention that some devices, has a limit in the size of the textures in pixels, this might be the ultimate limit of how large a single-texture background can be.

Comment: Thanks for a great response. Do you have a rule of thumb in terms of the largest image you would use for your adventure game?  What resolution did you use for iPad retina?

Comment: my adventure games we tried to go with full retina resolution, this means having the screen being 2048 pixels wide, thus we decided to make it non-scrolling and use 2048x2048 textures at most. This might allow it to work on some more recent android high-end tablets too.

The iPad3 supports 4096 textures, but with only 512mb of memory that  sounded as bad idea to me (and indeed, limiting ourselves to 2048 already make it run out of memory)

Comment: ok - so if you wanted on iPad3 to have a single image that was say 2 screens wide (scrolling game) then in this case would you recommend the approach whereby you do not provide a high resolution image background here, and let the iPad3 image fall back to a lower resolution version?

Comment: 2 screens wide you can use 4096x4096, and it will work on iPad3, but you need to take care to not use too much memory with other objects. Also, it won't work on some Android devices, but if you are going iOS only, go for it ;)